# Tough test polynomials for (finite precision) complex root finding methods, especially Aberth's method

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, roots, machine-precision

Today I have implemented [Aberth's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberth_method) for complex polynomial root finding. And I have to say I am enchanted about its astonishing performance and its intriguing simplicity. Before I go on believing (having quite some experience with numerics, I should say: naively) that this is a fool-proof all-purpose root finding method, I would like to challenge it a little.

Apart from Wilkinson's polynomial, are there other notorious polynomials that often cause root finding algorithms to fail?

Maybe someone even knows a case, where Aberth's method fails in particular?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, try https://scicomp.stackexchange.com